# Orthogonal eigenvectors and symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone point me to a paper, or show here, why symmetric matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors? In particular, I'd like to see proof of $Av$ and $Aw$ being orthogonal, assuming $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal eigenvectors of $A^{T}A$.

(A being an $m\times n$ matrix)

Answer (score 1):

This result is the Spectral Theorem: page 217 in Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right"